# InnoDB MySql Error 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint / even after removing cascade obligations on DELETE

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb

I'm trying to add foreign keys to my two tables Problem and File.
These are the CREATE queries.
And both tables are created successfully:

```
CREATE TABLE lpsolve.tbl_file (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  problem_id INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  title VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  description VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  type VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  create_time DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
CHARACTER SET latin1
COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;

CREATE TABLE lpsolve.tbl_probem (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  description VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  create_time DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  number_of_files INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
CHARACTER SET latin1
COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```

But when I try to add the following constraint I get the Error 1215 Error. This is the add constraint query:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_file
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_problem_file
FOREIGN KEY (problem_id)
REFERENCES tbl_problem(id) 
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE RESTRICT
```

The query does not work even by removing the `ON DELETE CASCADE` and `ON UPDATE RESTRICT` either. There are a couple of similar problems mentioned in Stack Overflow but they did not answer my problem unfortunately.

Error message:

```
Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Comment: Can you confirm the tables are InnoDB (as if you don't have InnoDB enabled, MySQL will create them with the default storage engine)

Comment: How can I confirm that? Except that when I try to edit my table in MySQL it gives me the create query that I pasted for you.

Comment: Even when I remove the DEFAULT NULL on the problem_id column in the File table I still get the same strange error.

Answer (score 0):

The table name is `tbl_probem`

```
CREATE TABLE lpsolve.tbl_probem (
```

but the ALTER command is trying to reference a table:`tbl_problem`

```
REFERENCES tbl_problem(id)
```

Delete `l` from `problem` to solve this problem.